# iOS App Development - Database

Tags: mysql, ios, database

I am currently working on an iOS application, and need to store data in a database(not locally). I have done some research on Core Data, but I want to store the data on a web server. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do that through some API like a RESTful service. I would do something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.website.com/restService"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithString:@"value1=test&value2=test2"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data somewhere on server  and you dont have server -you can use one fo the following:
1) iCloud
2) Parse - You can create database on parse.com and use that database directly with Parse API. look at https://parse.com/docs/index  for more detail.

Comment: Or in general, say Backend As A Service (BaaS)